# Redirect after authentication with HttpOnly cookie

Tags: http, authentication, redirect, nestjs, setcookie

My app looks like that:

- Client: Angular
- Web server: node.js + NestJS
- Login page: html document + jQqery served as a static by the server
- Auth mechanism: HttpOnly cookie

The user should fill the login form on `localhost:3000/login`
Then the request will sent to `localhost:3000/api/login` with the credentials.
After validation, the server should response with `Set-cookie` header and redirect to `localhost:4200`.
The HttpOnly cookie should be valid for both `localhost:3000` and `localhost:4200` domains.

What is the correct way to implement the redirect and `set-cookie`?

Comment: uhh, so to clarify a bit. this HttpOnly cookie refers to HttpOnly cookie? you want the cookie to be shared by both `localhost:3000` and `localhost:4200`? if both website sits on "localhost" i believe you can just set the domain to localhost for the cookie. however, if its two different domain later on, make sure they are sitting in subdomains (e.g. `local3000.myproductionwebsite.zzz` and `local4200.myproductionwebsite.zzz`) so you can set the domain for the cookie into `myproductionwebsite.zzz`. that being said.. sharing cookie isnt exactly the best way to authenticate user accross domains.